# How can I extract scene/place words in a sentence by using python packages like NLTK or stanfordcorenlp?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

Given sentences like:

```
'the people are all watching and listening to the bikers on the corner of the road'

'woman on snow skis being pulled by dogs.'

(Actually, the sentences I want to process are captions in MSCOCO datatset)
```

I want to **extract the scene/place words in the sentence**. For example, 'road', 'snow' here are the scene/place words.

I have tried NER in stanfordcorenlp, but it can only extract the location name, not a scene word.

Could anyone give me a clue about how to extract such words?
Thanks.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question

Answer (score 0):

You can train your own NER model or try to find one that you fit your needs. If you decide going with the first, the official documentation describes how to do that: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#a

Godd luck!